# CSS - Making algolia dropdown menu with results go over the dropdown menu of bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, algolia

I have a navbar with a search form, where I get the results from Algolia with their autocomplete solution. This is the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div id="nav-icon1" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
          <img class="logo logo-small" src="{{ asset('/img/logo-small.png') }}" alt="logo">
          <img class="logo logo-big" src="{{ asset('/img/m2.png') }}" alt="logo">
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <form action="/search" method="get" class="navbar-form navbar-search-form active" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="submit"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i></button>
              </span>
              <input type="text" id="search-input" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for videos or players..." value="{{ Request::get('q') }}" autofocus>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ url('/login') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

On small screens I have a problem, that the results are inside of the navbar dropdown menu
[image]

Where I would like them to go over the dropdown menu. I have tried with setting the z-index for various elements of algolia dropdown:

```
.algolia-autocomplete {
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

But that didn't work, not sure where exactly should I change the z-index, since the element is created on autocomplete so I am not able to see the structure before I type in something. How can I fix that?

Comment: Read about the [CSS stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have tried with setting the z-index for various elements of algolia dropdown, but nothing worked, not sure where exactly should I change the z-index, since the element is created on autocomplete so I am not able to see the structure before I type in something.

Comment: Could you try out the following? https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/issues/181

Comment: I have tried out now, but it didn't help either

Comment: Few people seem to understand how `z-index` actually works. It's not an absolute context...and it's not the only thing that controls stacking. Seriously, [read the damn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: @AndréDion Yes, I did read it, and the problem was not in stacking, it was stacking ok, I just had to change the overflow on the y axis of the navbar collapse elements

Comment: That's great that you found a solution, my comment is aimed at `z-index: 99999 !important` which is a telltale sign of someone not understanding `z-index`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was in the bootstrap class:

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I had to change it to `overflow-y: visible;` and then it worked.